# Pass Webdriver instance from one method to another method(in same class) in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have totally four methods in my class

I have created a static `WebDriver` object

```
static WebDriver driver;
```

Method 1: Log-in to site ( Here I initialize the `WebDriver driver=new new FirefoxDriver();`)

Method 2: Click a link in site ( Using WebDriver driver)
On click, the link gets opened in new tab in same browser

Method 3:

Now in Method 3, I switch to new tab and perform some actions with web element in the new tab

Below code is used to switch to new tab

```
ArrayList<String> tabss = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabss.get(1));
```

Method 4: Again I want to perform some more action in the new tab

Now I need the same driver instance (tab) used in Method 3 in Method 4.

How do I get that

If I use "driver" in Method 4, it's null.

```
public class download {
    static WebDriver driver;


    @Test
    public static void login() throws InterruptedException
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("__site__");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login-email")).sendKeys("__username__");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login-password")).sendKeys("__password__");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login-submit")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }


    @Test
    public static void navigatetolearningpage() throws InterruptedException
    {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='relative ember-view']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }

    @Test
    public static void search() throws InterruptedException, AWTException
    {

        ArrayList<String> tabss = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabss.get(1));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("__searchkeyword__");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='search-facet__label']")).click();

    }

    @Test 
    public static void course_list() throws InterruptedException
    {
        //This driver will print as NULL
        System.out.println("last method:"+driver);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the tests isn't guaranteed, so you need to initialize `driver` at start of the tests

Move the initialization code to the declaration of `driver`:

```
static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

**EDIT**

Following @Laazo comment,
I think it's better than add it to `@BeforeClass` Because if you switch to TestNG framework you will need to change or upgrade to JUnit5 to @BeforeAll

Comment: Doing the initialisation in a`@BeforeClass` would also work?

Comment: @Laazo I don't think it's needed, also if you switch to TestNG framework you will need to change or JUnit5 to `@BeforeAll`

Comment: @user7294900 can you please tell what was the mistake. Can you point out any resources to understand, about it clearly will be helpful

Comment: @KandanSiva the order of the tests isn't guaranteed, so you need to initialize at start

Comment: @user7294900 Suppose if I maintain the order using priority  for each test(@Test). Then still we need to initialization  out of methods?

Comment: @KandanSiva each test should work as standalone test. For example if you execute specific tests or exclude test(s). So you must use initialization code